# Sub-windows created by an add-in

Tags: vba, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I have seen several times that an add-in can create sub-windows in Excel. Here is an exemple:

[image]

Does anyone know which technique allows the add-in to create the sub-windows on the right hand side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique  is [CustomTaskPanes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx)