# Implement a point highlighting a line of text in CustomTaskPanes

Tags: winforms, vba, vsto, excel-addins, customtaskpane

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188359/sub-windows-created-by-an-add-in) about [CustomTaskPanes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It seems that we can implement lots of things inside a pane.

I think it is totally feasible to have a pane to display a program (in VBA or in other languages) or a text, my question is if it is possible to implement a point that allow users to highlight a line of text. It looks like a "breakpoint", but does not necessarily work exactly like a breakpoint for debugging. The implementation of this kind of point does not seem straightforward to me. Does anyone know if there is any technique inside CustomTaskPanes to do so?

PS: I made an image to illustrate the point, let's assume the pane is inside the excel editor and is a CustomTaskPane.

[image]

Comment: CustomTaskPanes are basically Windows Forms controls. So you really should explore this from the Windows Forms aspect. If you can figure out how to do it using what's available in Windows Forms, use that information to create a custom Windows Forms "User control" and add that to the CustomTaskPane.

Comment: Thank you... I just added another tag `winforms`, and we will see if anyone knows how to do it in Windows Forms.